# Split rows when importing csv to R

Tags: r, csv, import

I have a large csv file in which random rows end with the following string: /\r/. The next row after this should be a continuation of the previous row but instead it is treated as a new one. What function should be applied to fix this? So far I have managed to locate the corrupted rows by importing csv to R as a vector of strings i.e. I used a delimited which doesn't occur in the file so R read the whole row as one column. Now I would like to paste together row which ends with the above mentioned string and the row which occurs after it.

Example here:

```
"CLSL;2017-01-09;PA930082402;23;10986450"
"CLNA;2016-09-05 /\r/"
";650963783;1;60010670"
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
"CLSL;2017-01-09;PA930082402;23;10986450"
"CLNA;2016-09-05;650963783;1;60010670"
```

Comment: Is that `\r` a literal text, or just a marker for a carriage return which you've already formatted?

Comment: I didnt format anything. I got the EOF error while importing with fread so I imported the file just as I wrote above, as a whole rów in one column. The file is too big to fix those errors manually, for example in notepad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
#read file
txt <- readLines("test.csv")

#find row index of junk value
idx <- which(grepl(" /\\\\r/", txt))
#append next immediate row with the row having junk value
txt[idx] <- paste0(txt[idx], txt[idx+1])
txt <- txt[-(idx+1)]

#remove junk value
txt <- gsub(" /\\\\r/", "", txt)
```

**Output is:**

```
> txt
[1] "CLSL;2017-01-09;PA930082402;23;10986450" "CLNA;2016-09-05;650963783;1;60010670"
```

**Sample data:**
`test.csv` contains

```
CLSL;2017-01-09;PA930082402;23;10986450
CLNA;2016-09-05 /\r/
;650963783;1;60010670
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution here is likely to add quotes to the values in whatever database your csv is sourced from, but short of that, this is is one way to combine the character vector you have into a data.frame.

```
tt <- c("CLSL;2017-01-09;PA930082402;23;10986450", 
        "CLNA;2016-09-05 /\r/", ";650963783;1;60010670",
        "CLSL;2017-01-09;PA930082402;23;10986450", 
        "CLNA;2016-09-05 /\r/", ";650963783;1;60010670")

tt <- sub(" /\r/\n", "", paste0(tt, "\n"))
tt <- paste(tt, collapse="")
read.csv2(text=tt, header=FALSE)

#     V1         V2          V3 V4       V5
# 1 CLSL 2017-01-09 PA930082402 23 10986450
# 2 CLNA 2016-09-05   650963783  1 60010670
# 3 CLSL 2017-01-09 PA930082402 23 10986450
# 4 CLNA 2016-09-05   650963783  1 60010670
```